# Trouble running a parser created using scrapy with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a scraper in Python scrapy in combination with selenium to scrape some `titles` from a website. The `css selectors` defined within my scraper is flawless. I wish my scraper to keep on clicking on the next page and parse the information embedded in each page. It is doing fine for the first page but when it comes to play the role for selenium part the scraper keeps clicking on the same link over and over again.

As this is my first time to work with selenium along with scrapy, I don't have any idea to move on successfully. Any fix will be highly appreciated.

If I try like this then it works smoothly (there is nothing wrong with selectors):

```
class IncomeTaxSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "taxspider"

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Pages/utilities/exempted-institutions.aspx',
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

    def parse(self,response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        while True:
            for elem in self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h1.faqsno-heading"))):
                name = elem.find_element_by_css_selector("div[id^='arrowex']").text
                print(name)

            try:
                self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id$='_imgbtnNext']"))).click()
                self.wait.until(EC.staleness_of(elem))
            except TimeoutException:break
```

But my intention is to make my script run this way:

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

class IncomeTaxSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "taxspider"

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Pages/utilities/exempted-institutions.aspx',
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

    def click_nextpage(self,link):
        self.driver.get(link)
        elem = self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id^='arrowex']")))

        #It keeeps clicking on the same link over and over again

        self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id$='_imgbtnNext']"))).click()  
        self.wait.until(EC.staleness_of(elem))


    def parse(self,response):
        while True:
            for item in response.css("h1.faqsno-heading"):
                name = item.css("div[id^='arrowex']::text").extract_first()
                yield {"Name": name}

            try:
                self.click_nextpage(response.url) #initiate the method to do the clicking
            except TimeoutException:break
```

These are the titles visible on that landing page (to let you know what I'm after):

```
INDIA INCLUSION FOUNDATION
INDIAN WILDLIFE CONSERVATION TRUST
VATSALYA URBAN AND RURAL DEVELOPMENT TRUST
```

***I'm not willing to get the data from that site, so any alternative approach other than what I've tried above is useless to me. My only intention is to have any solution related to the way I tried in my second approach.***

Comment: is the "next" button generated dynamically?? if not, why not use a Scrapy to traverse from page to page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial code was almost correct with one key piece missing from it. You were using the same response object always. The response object needs to be from the latest page source.

Also you were browsing the link again and again in click next page which was resetting it to page 1 every time. That is why you get page 1 and 2 (max). You need to get the url only once in the parse stage and then let the next page click to happen

Below is final code working fine

```
class IncomeTaxSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "taxspider"

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Pages/utilities/exempted-institutions.aspx',
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

    def click_nextpage(self,link):
        # self.driver.get(link)
        elem = self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id^='arrowex']")))

        #It keeeps clicking on the same link over and over again

        self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id$='_imgbtnNext']"))).click()
        self.wait.until(EC.staleness_of(elem))


    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        while True:
            for item in response.css("h1.faqsno-heading"):
                name = item.css("div[id^='arrowex']::text").extract_first()
                yield {"Name": name}

            try:
                self.click_nextpage(response.url) #initiate the method to do the clicking
                response = response.replace(body=self.driver.page_source)
            except TimeoutException:break
```

After that change it works perfect

[image: Working]

Comment: When I created this post I was seriously expecting your intervention cause I always find your solution very helpful. However, as for your answer: it gives me the content of the `first page` and then `second page` and then again `second page` and so on. It doesn't (or can't) go to the third page, fourth page etc.

Comment: Let me debug, I saw content changing so didn't go further. But this may be a CSS issue then

Comment: @Topto, issue resolved, please look at the updated answer

Comment: I can't wait any longer to see when your answer is gonna get the bounty. It perfectly did the job. A oneliner clarification as to why you used `self.driver.get(response.url)` before `while loop` in `parse` method will be very helpful. Apology for the ignorance. Thanks and congrats.

Comment: We need the browser to be on the first page before we starting clicking the url. We could have done that in `__init__` also, or here in parse. The key is browse the first page only once and not while moving to next page

Comment: Sorry Tarun Lalwani , I can't award this bounty until 13 hours from now. The system doesn't allow me to do so and yes this is the answer what does worth it.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need pure Selenium solution:

```
driver.get("https://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Pages/utilities/exempted-institutions.aspx")

while True:
    for item in wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id^='arrowex']"))):
        print(item.text)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@text='Next' and not(contains(@class, 'disabledImageButton'))]").click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for your input sir. I wish to accomplish the project in combination with scrapy.

Answer (score 1):

```
import scrapy
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class IncomeTaxSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "taxspider"

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Pages/utilities/exempted-institutions.aspx',
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

        link = 'https://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Pages/utilities/exempted-institutions.aspx'
        self.driver.get(link)

    def click_nextpage(self):        
        elem = self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id^='arrowex']")))

        #It keeeps clicking on the same link over and over again

        self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id$='_imgbtnNext']"))).click()  
        self.wait.until(EC.staleness_of(elem))
        time.sleep(4)

    def parse(self,response):
        while True:
            for item in response.css("h1.faqsno-heading"):
                name = item.css("div[id^='arrowex']::text").extract_first()
                yield {"Name": name}

            try:
                self.click_nextpage() #initiate the method to do the clicking
            except TimeoutException:break

process = CrawlerProcess()

process.crawl(IncomeTaxSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: Thanks @Maxwell77, for your solution. It is very close to what I was expecting. Your provided script is able to click links incrementally. However, I'm still having the same data from the first page over and over again. I think it is only possible If we could pass `self.driver.page_source` to `self.parse` method from within `click_nextpage(self)` method after `time.sleep(4)` .

Comment: Sorry, I have tested the script and it's working on my computer. I think it is not necessary to pass the page source because it is always the same url, it's only the content which is reloaded with the new information.

Comment: You didn't get my point. When the driver clicks on the next page link then `driver.page_source` surely be different. I'm not talking about `driver.url`, it's the `driver.page_source`. However, if you take a closer look at the spider then you can see that `self.parse()` method never gets update with the new response that is the only reason why the content I'm having are always the same. Thanks. Btw, I tested again to be sure and found the same result as I've already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the page gets loaded using the 'Next Page' arrow (using Selenium) it gets reset back to Page '1'. Not sure about the reason for this (may be the java script)
Hence changed the approach to use the input field to enter the page number needed and hitting ENTER key to navigate.

Here is the modified code. Hope this may be useful for you.

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class IncomeTaxSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "taxspider"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Pages/utilities/exempted-institutions.aspx',
    ]
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

    def click_nextpage(self,link, number):
        self.driver.get(link)
        elem = self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id^='arrowex']")))

        #It keeeps clicking on the same link over and over again

    inputElement = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_d6877ff2_42a8_4804_8802_6d49230dae8a_ctl00_txtPageNumber']")
    inputElement.clear()
    inputElement.send_keys(number)
    inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        self.wait.until(EC.staleness_of(elem))


    def parse(self,response):
        number = 1
        while number < 10412: #Website shows it has 10411 pages.
            for item in response.css("h1.faqsno-heading"):
                name = item.css("div[id^='arrowex']::text").extract_first()
                yield {"Name": name}
                print (name)

            try:
                number += 1
                self.click_nextpage(response.url, number) #initiate the method to do the clicking
            except TimeoutException:break
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Krishna. Although your script appears to change the page number by entering that harcoded number in that inputbox, but It still gives me the same output over and over again (output from the first page).

Answer (score 0):

Create a self.page_num or something.

```
def parse(self,response):
    self.pages = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_d6877ff2_42a8_4804_8802_6d49230dae8a_ctl00_totalRecordsDiv.act_search_footer span")
    self.pages = int(self.pages.split('of ')[1].split(']')[0])

    self.page_num = 1

    while self.page_num <= self.pages:
        for item in response.css("h1.faqsno-heading"):
            name = item.css("div[id^='arrowex']::text").extract_first()
            yield {"Name": name}

        try:
            self.click_nextpage(response.url) #initiate the method to do the clicking
        except TimeoutException:break

def click_nextpage(self,link):
    self.driver.get(link)
    elem = self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id^='arrowex']")))

    page_link = 'ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_d6877ff2_42a8_4804_8802_6d49230dae8a_ctl00_lnkBtn_' + str(self.page_num)
    self.page_num = self.page_num + 1


    self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id$='_imgbtnNext']"))).click()  
    self.wait.until(EC.staleness_of(elem))
```