# Can't fetch two fields accordingly from a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to get two fields from a webpage. I have tried one item (the first one conditionally) and the other one using list comprehension. Finally, I've appended them to a list to print the result.

I've two questions:

1. What is the ideal way to parse one item conditionally and the other one using list comprehension within the same for loop.
2. When i print the result, i get them like following

   [[], [], [], 'EUROMESSAGE EXPRESS', [], [], [], [], [], [], [], ['info@euromessageexpress.com'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

My expected output:

```
EUROMESSAGE EXPRESS info@euromessageexpress.com
```

Not like this:

```
EUROMESSAGE EXPRESS 
info@euromessageexpress.com
```

[Link to the webpage](http://www.fretonline.com/Transport.php?transporteur=EUROM2OCAS&&Nom_Transporteur=EUROMESSAGE_EXPRESS&&Transport_Ville=CASABLANCA)

This is my script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "find the url above"

req = requests.get(url)
sauce = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")

data = []
for items in sauce.select_one("table[width='610']").select("tr"):
    for item in items.select("td"):
        if "Raison" in item.text:
            raison = item.find_next_sibling().get_text(strip=True)
            data.append(raison)

    email = [item.text for item in items.select("a[href^='mailto:']")]
    data.append(email)

print(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code lines to get required output:

```
items = sauce.select_one("table[width='610']").select("tr")
raison, email = [item.select("td")[-1].text.strip() for item in items if item.select("a[href^='mailto:']") or "Raison" in item.text]

print(raison, email)
```

Comment: Yes, it perfectly gets me there. A little elaboration would be very helpful. Thanks sir.

Comment: Do you mean you need some clarifications about what the code actually does?

Comment: Yes, sir. Your code never fails but I sometimes find it difficult to understand the steps because of my shallow knowledge.

Comment: `item.select("td")[-1].text.strip() for item in items` means *return the list of the text nodes of each last "td" node from each "tr" node*. `if item.select("a[href^='mailto:']") or "Raison" in item.text` means *return not from every "tr" node, but only from those who has required link or contains substring "Raison"*. As we know that there are only two nodes that could met our condition, we can simply assign `raison, email = [first_item, second_item]`

Comment: Have you worked with scrapy project, sir? If it is mind taking a look [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788131/trouble-running-a-parser-created-using-scrapy-with-selenium) in your spare time. I requested only because i know you are a master of selenium. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure I can easily get desired output with Selenium, but I don't really like Scrapy and didn't use it on real Projects, so I have no idea how to use both tools together