# scrapy response is nothing like the page source

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to using scrapy shell to get in "ykc1.greatwestlife.com" which should be a public website, though there are lots of things if I look at page source manually, I can not get a correct response using scrapy.

[scrapy shell response result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1bon.png)

Do I need to use scrapy-splash in this case?
any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What version on python you have?

Comment: You can use scrapy with selenium, Please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788131/trouble-running-a-parser-created-using-scrapy-with-selenium. Hope its may help you.

Comment: python 3.7, does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually see the two back-to-back requests, caused by

```html
      <head>
        <script language="javascript">
            document.cookie = "cmsUserPortalLocale=en;path=/";
            document.cookie = "cmsTheme=advgwl;path=/";    
            document.cookie = "siteBrand="+escape(location.hostname)+"; path=/";
            window.location.reload(true);
        </script>
```

[image: the back-to-back requests]

where the first request is substantially smaller, and likely causing what you're experiencing. Thankfully, since the cookies appear to be static, you can reproduce that behavior quite easily:

```py
def parse(self, response):
    # this is required because the response that arrives to parse()
    # has session cookies but we need to add 3 more to them
    new_cookies = {
      "cmsUserPortalLocale": "en",
      "cmsTheme": "advgwl",
      "siteBrand": "ykc1.greatwestlife.com",
    }
    yield response.follow(url=request.url, cookies=new_cookies,
                          callback=self.parse_home)

def parse_home(self, response):
    # and now you have the full body
```

Comment: this is great, it works now, thanks you so much, mdaniel

Comment: I'm glad; if you can mark the answer as accepted, it'll let other people know that the solution worked for you